# Family instance of t4g and m6gd.xlarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I use the AWS EKS Quickstart to launch a cluster
I select "t4g.small" or "m6gd.xlarge" as the instance type and "General" as the instance family. But it looks like that is incorrect, is it supposed to be "ARM"? isn't it?

Can I have the "instance family" information from where?

I got an error while deploying the cloudformation stack

> Parameter validation failed: assertion error: Valid instance types for the "Standard" instance family are: "t3a.nano", "t3.nano", "t2.nano", "t3a.micro", "t3.micro", "t2.micro", "t3a.small", "t1.micro", "t3.small", "t2.small", "t3a.medium", "t3.medium", "m1.small", "t2.medium", "m3.medium", "t3a.large", "c5a.large", "t3.large", "c5.large", "m5a.large", "c5ad.large", "m1.medium", "t2.large", "c5d.large", "m5.large", "c4.large", "m4.large", "m5ad.large", "c3.large", "c5n.large", "m5d.large", "r5a.large", "m5n.large", "r5.large", "c1.medium", "r5ad.large", "m3.large", "r4.large", "m5dn.large", "r5d.large", "r5n.large", "t3a.xlarge", "c5a.xlarge", "i3.large", "r3.large", "t3.xlarge", "r5dn.large", "c5.xlarge", "c5ad.xlarge", "m5a.xlarge", "m1.large", "t2.xlarge", "z1d.large", "m5.xlarge", "c5d.xlarge", "c4.xlarge", "m4.xlarge", "m5ad.xlarge", "c3.xlarge", "c5n.xlarge", "r5a.xlarge", "m5d.xlarge", "i3en.large", "m5n.xlarge", "m2.xlarge", "r5.xlarge", "r5ad.xlarge", "m3.xlarge", "r4.xlarge", "m5dn.xlarge", "r5d.xlarge", "r5n.xlarge", "t3a.2xlarge", "c5a.2xlarge", "i3.xlarge", "t3.2xlarge", "r3.xlarge", "r5dn.xlarge", "c5.2xlarge", "m5a.2xlarge", "c5ad.2xlarge", "m1.xlarge", "inf1.xlarge", "t2.2xlarge", "z1d.xlarge", "c5d.2xlarge", "m5.2xlarge", "c4.2xlarge", "m4.2xlarge", "m5ad.2xlarge", "c3.2xlarge", "c5n.2xlarge", "r5a.2xlarge", "m5d.2xlarge", "i3en.xlarge", "h1.2xlarge", "m5n.2xlarge", "m2.2xlarge", "r5.2xlarge", "c1.xlarge", "r5ad.2xlarge", "g4dn.xlarge", "r4.2xlarge", "m3.2xlarge", "m5dn.2xlarge", "r5d.2xlarge", "inf1.2xlarge", "r5n.2xlarge", "c5a.4xlarge", "i3.2xlarge", "g2.2xlarge", "r3.2xlarge", "r5dn.2xlarge", "c5.4xlarge", "m5a.4xlarge", "c5ad.4xlarge", "d2.xlarge", "z1d.2xlarge", "g3s.xlarge", "g4dn.2xlarge", "c5d.4xlarge", "m5.4xlarge", "c4.4xlarge", "m4.4xlarge", "m5ad.4xlarge", "x1e.xlarge", "c3.4xlarge", "i2.xlarge", "c5n.4xlarge", "p2.xlarge", "r5a.4xlarge", "i3en.2xlarge", "m5d.4xlarge", "h1.4xlarge", "m5n.4xlarge", "m2.4xlarge", "r5.4xlarge", "r5ad.4xlarge", "r4.4xlarge", "m5dn.4xlarge", "z1d.3xlarge", "g3.4xlarge", "r5d.4xlarge", "r5n.4xlarge", "g4dn.4xlarge", "c5a.8xlarge", "i3.4xlarge", "r3.4xlarge", "r5dn.4xlarge", "i3en.3xlarge", "m5a.8xlarge", "c5ad.8xlarge", "d2.2xlarge", "c5.9xlarge", "m5.8xlarge", "c4.8xlarge", "m5ad.8xlarge", "f1.2xlarge", "x1e.2xlarge", "c3.8xlarge", "i2.2xlarge", "c5d.9xlarge", "m5d.8xlarge", "r5a.8xlarge", "c5a.12xlarge", "h1.8xlarge", "m5n.8xlarge", "inf1.6xlarge", "c5n.9xlarge", "i3en.24xlarge", "i3en.metal", "p3.8xlarge", "f1.16xlarge", "x1.32xlarge", "x1e.16xlarge", "p2.16xlarge", "m4.10xlarge", "cc2.8xlarge", "r5.8xlarge", "c5.12xlarge", "c5ad.12xlarge", "m5a.12xlarge", "r5ad.8xlarge", "r4.8xlarge", "m5dn.8xlarge", "g4dn.8xlarge", "z1d.6xlarge", "g3.8xlarge", "m5.12xlarge", "c5d.12xlarge", "r5d.8xlarge", "r5n.8xlarge", "c5a.16xlarge", "m5ad.12xlarge", "i3.8xlarge", "g2.8xlarge", "r3.8xlarge", "r5dn.8xlarge", "r5a.12xlarge", "m5d.12xlarge", "i3en.6xlarge", "m5a.16xlarge", "c5ad.16xlarge", "d2.4xlarge", "m5n.12xlarge", "p3.16xlarge", "x1e.32xlarge", "r5.12xlarge", "p3.2xlarge", "c5.18xlarge", "m5.16xlarge", "r5ad.12xlarge", "m4.16xlarge", "m5dn.12xlarge", "m5ad.16xlarge", "f1.4xlarge", "x1e.4xlarge", "i2.4xlarge", "c5d.18xlarge", "r5d.12xlarge", "r5n.12xlarge", "m5d.16xlarge", "r5a.16xlarge", "c5a.24xlarge", "h1.16xlarge", "m5n.16xlarge", "c5n.18xlarge", "c5n.metal", "g4dn.12xlarge", "p3dn.24xlarge", "r5dn.12xlarge", "r5.16xlarge", "c5.24xlarge", "c5.metal", "c5ad.24xlarge", "m5a.24xlarge", "r5ad.16xlarge", "r4.16xlarge", "m5dn.16xlarge", "g4dn.16xlarge", "z1d.metal", "z1d.12xlarge", "g3.16xlarge", "m5.24xlarge", "m5.metal", "r5d.16xlarge", "c5d.24xlarge", "c5d.metal", "r5n.16xlarge", "m5ad.24xlarge", "i3.16xlarge", "i3.metal", "r5dn.16xlarge", "i3en.12xlarge", "m5d.metal", "m5d.24xlarge", "r5a.24xlarge", "d2.8xlarge", "m5n.24xlarge", "r5.24xlarge", "r5.metal", "r5ad.24xlarge", "m5dn.24xlarge", "x1.16xlarge", "x1e.8xlarge", "i2.8xlarge", "r5d.24xlarge", "r5d.metal", "r5n.24xlarge", "p2.8xlarge", "inf1.24xlarge", "g4dn.metal", "r5dn.24xlarge"

Edit to provide more infor:

a) the quickstart I used: https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-amazon-eks/

b) deploy a new VPC: https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-2#/stacks/create/template?stackName=Amazon-EKS&templateURL=https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-amazon-eks/templates/amazon-eks-entrypoint-new-vpc.template.yaml

Comment: Yes, those two instance types use ARM processors: [Amazon EC2 Instance Types - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). The QuickStart you are using is probably out-of-date. Can you add a link in your Question?

Comment: Please never share pure text content as a screenshot. Also, please share more details about this problem - is this even related to programming?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I edited to provide the link of quickstart I used, thanks

Comment: There is a "Send feedback" section in that guide. I suggest you let them know about this issue.